# Python beginner's tree with unit tests

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, unit-testing, tree

I have implemented a tree in Python. However, due to my lack of experience with Python, I am not able to judge the overall quality of my code.

```
import unittest
from datetime import *
from gc import *

RET_NO = 0
RET_YES = 1
RET_MAYBE = 0.5 # haha :)


class Tree(object):
    """
    Mutable abstract data type for arbitrary data with O(N) access on elements.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, element):

        if self.root:
            self.root.insert(element)
        else:
            self.root = Node(element)

    def contains(self, element):
        if self.root is None:
            print 'WARN: Contains() called before elements were inserted!!'
            raise Exception()

        return self.root.contains(element) if self.root else RET_NO

    def size(self):
        return self.root.size() if self.root else 0

    def bulk_insert(self, elements=[]):
        while len(elements):
            self.insert(element[0])
            elements = elements[1:]

class Node(object):
    """
    Node class to be used in Tree instances.
    """
    def __init__(self, element):
        super(Node, self).__init__()
        self.element = element
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, element):
        if self.element == element:
            return
        if element < self.element:
            if self.left:
                self.left.insert(element)
            else:
                self.left = Node(element)
        else:
            if self.right:
                self.right.insert(element)
            else:
                self.right = Node(element)
        raise Exception('Should never reach this line!')

    def contains(self, element):
        if self.element == element:
            return RET_YES
        if element < self.element:
            if self.left:
                return self.left.contains(element)
            else:
                return RET_NO
        else:
            if self.right:
                return self.right.contains(element)
            else:
                return RET_NO
        raise Exception('Should never reach this line!')

    def size(self):
        """
        Return size
        """
        left_size = self.left.size() if self.left else 0
        right_size = self.right.size() if self.right else 0
        return left_size + right_size + 1

class TreeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # no setup required yet
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        # leave memory in a clean state
        gc.collect()


    def test_1(self):
        #tree = Tree()
        #self.assertEqual(tree.size(), 0)
        #tree.insert(10)
        #self.assertEqual(tree.size(), 10)
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_2(self):
        start = datetime.now()

        elements = []
        for i in range(1000000):
            elements += [i]

        tree = Tree()
        # tree should be empty
        for i in elements:
            self.assertEqual(tree.contains(i), RET_NO)
        # fill tree
        for i in elements:
            tree.insert(i)
        # tree should be full
        for i in elements:
            self.assertEqual(tree.contains(i), RET_YES)

        end = datetime.now()
        elapsed = end - start
        # must not take longer than a minute
        self.assertTrue(elasped.total_seconds() < 60)

    def test_3(self):
        tree = Tree()
        try:
            tree.contains(1)
            # should have thrown an exception -> test failed
            self.assertTrue(False)
        except Exception, ValueError:
            # expected to raise an Exception -> test should pass
            self.assertTrue(True)
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't do `from something import *`.

   Either import what you need:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime
   ```

   Or import the entire module and use qualified names:

   ```
   import datetime
   ...
       start = datetime.datetime.now()
   ```

   Importing everything is dangerous because it can shadow already existing names. One such example:

   ```
   import datetime
   from datetime import *
   # `datetime` as a class shadows `datetime` as a module
   ```

   You might want to do a little [reading](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/importing-star-in-python) on the subject.

---

2. This whole thing makes no sense:

   ```
   RET_NO = 0
   RET_YES = 1
   RET_MAYBE = 0.5 # haha :)
   ```

   Instead of `RET_YES` / `RET_NO` you sould use `True` and `False`.

---

3. You don't have to call `super(...).__init__`  if the class only inherits from `object`.

---

4. Why do you print something to stdout and then raise an empty exception?

   Instead of

   ```
   print 'WARN: Contains() called before elements were inserted!!'
   raise Exception()
   ```

   you should do

   ```
   raise Exception('contains() called on empty tree')
   ```

---

5. In the method `Tree.contains`, you already checked if `self.root is None`, so this

   ```
   return self.root.contains(element) if self.root else RET_NO
   ```

   can be simplified to this

   ```
   return self.root.contains(element)
   ```

---

6. Instead of `contains` you can define the [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method. Then you can use the `in` keyword:

   ```
   return element in self.root
   ```

   Although in this particular case it's less readable, so it's probably better to just stick with `contains`.

---

7. Method `Tree.bulk_insert` is just wrong. There's no point in having an empty list for a default argument. In the `for` loop you *modify the list* while iterating over it, and on each iteration you call the `len` function. Why? Even the C-style

   ```
   for i in range(len(elements)):
       self.insert(elements[i])
   ```

   would have been better.

   This is the way to do it in Python:

   ```
   def bulk_insert(self, elements):
       for element in elements:
           self.insert(element)
   ```

   That way `elements` doesn't have to be a `list`, it can be any [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-iterable).

---

8. Does your tree have a special requirement that it cannot contain the same element twice? If not, then in `Node.insert` there should be no

   ```
   if self.element == element:
       return
   ```

---

9. Remove unreachable statements. There's *no point* in having

   ```
   raise Exception('Should never reach this line!')
   ```

   in `Node.contains`, while having it in `Node.insert` effectively makes the method raise an exception in almost all cases. Actually if you fix the error mentioned in the previous point, it would be in completely all cases.

---

10. The comment

    ```
    """
    Return size
    """
    ```

    is pointless. The method itself is called `size`, so it's obvious that it returns size. Also, the name `size` is quite ambiguous to begin with. Either don't restate code in comments, or actually explain what the method does (eg. *how* do you compute the size). A more suitable name would be `number_of_elements`, or maybe something shorter but descriptive like `nelems`.

---

11. The docstring of `Node` states:

    ```
    """
    Node class to be used in Tree instances.
    """
    ```

    I'd say it can possibly be used in other classes than `Tree`, so don't create a tight coupling between the two, even if it's just in comments.

---

12. `size` can be a property:

    ```
    @property
    def size(self):
        ...
    ```

    That way you won't have to call it:

    ```
    left_size = self.left.size if self.left else 0
    ```

---

13. Even tests should be documented. Add docstrings explaining what do the `test_*` methods test. Your non-test code also lacks documentation.

---

14. The docstring of `Tree` says *"O(N) access on elements"*. This is not quite true, for two reasons:

    - your `Tree` and `Node` classes don't even allow you to access elements, they only allow you to check whether an element is present in the tree,
    - \$O(n)\$ is the worst case; average asymptotic complexity is \$O(log(n))\$.

---

15. Have you by chance forgotten to implement a `remove` method? Or you just wanted an insert-only tree?

$$⸻$$